# Xml code in my database

Tags: c#, sql, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
 <ColSettings>
<Column1>Column1</Column1>
<Column2>Column2</Column2>
<Column3>Column3</Column3>
<Column4>Column4</Column4>
<Column5>Column5</Column5>
<Column6>Column6</Column6>
<Column7>Column7</Column7>
<Column8>Column8</Column8>
<Column9>Column9</Column9>
<Column10>Column10</Column10>
  </ColSettings>
  <ColSettings>
<Column1>Symbol</Column1>
<Column2>Bid</Column2>
<Column3>Ask</Column3>
<Column4>DHS</Column4>
<Column5>PKR</Column5>
<Column6>High</Column6>
<Column7>Low</Column7>
<Column8>TTRate</Column8>
<Column9>Comm</Column9>
<Column10>SelRate</Column10>
  </ColSettings>
  <ColSettings>
<Column1>1</Column1>
<Column2>2</Column2>
<Column3>3</Column3>
<Column4>4</Column4>
<Column5>5</Column5>
<Column6>6</Column6>
<Column7>7</Column7>
<Column8>8</Column8>
<Column9>9</Column9>
<Column10>10</Column10>
  </ColSettings>
  <ColSettings>
<Column1>#FFFFFF</Column1>
<Column2>#214488</Column2>
<Column3>#D8FF7C</Column3>
<Column4>#BE7400</Column4>
<Column5>#FFFFFF</Column5>
<Column6>#FFFFFF</Column6>
<Column7>#FFFFFF</Column7>
<Column8>#FFFFFF</Column8>
<Column9>#000000</Column9>
<Column10>#000000</Column10>
  </ColSettings>
  <ColSettings>
<Column1>#FFFFFF</Column1>
<Column2>#FFFFFF</Column2>
<Column3>#32CD32</Column3>
<Column4>#214488</Column4>
<Column5>#000000</Column5>
<Column6>#127332</Column6>
<Column7>#FF2121</Column7>
<Column8>#32CD32</Column8>
<Column9>#FF4800</Column9>
<Column10>#FF4800</Column10>
  </ColSettings>
</NewDataSet>
```

hi Friends i want to store given code in my Database column suggest me how can i do either by store procedure or c#.net code give me some code or related web site so that  store it in my database i am trying from 2 days ...

Comment: What do you want to do with that code one time it was stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the xml in datatable.

```
 ds.ReadXml(xmlPath);
```

Then you can refer following post

[How to insert multiple records with table param in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295326/should-you-make-multiple-insert-calls-or-pass-xml/10295812#10295812)