# Insert into Table use Array in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert

This is my table:

**Phone**: Id, MemberId, Number, PhoneType, IsDefault

I need an stored procedure to get an array of `numbers` and a `memberId` as argument and insert all of them to `Phone` Table. I can't pass numbers one by one I need to insert all of them or none of them. I think to pass numbers  as a list of separated by comma `Nvarchar` like `'0412589, 0425896, 04789652'` I must mention `MemberId` is always constant and pass by argument, `PhoneType` always constant `='phone'`, and for first number of array `IsDefault = 1` for others `IsDefault = 0` How can I select Numbers from `numbers` and set other columns in insert command? Or you have another suggestion to pass array of numbers?

Answer (score 6):

You could use Table-Valued Parameters. So if you have a type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE PhoneNumberType AS TABLE 
( number  VARCHAR(50));
GO
```

Then you procedure would be something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. usp_InsertPhoneNumbers
    @TVP PhoneNumberType READONLY
AS 
INSERT INTO Phone(number,....)
SELECT
    number,
    ....
FROM
    @TVP
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

**EDIT**

It worked just like a table so it is quite easy to do this:

```
DECLARE @TVP PhoneNumberType

INSERT INTO @TVP
VALUES
    ('0412589'),('0425896'),('04789652')

EXEC usp_InsertPhoneNumbers @TVP
```

Or if you have it as one string then you need to split it. Here is a neat split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@s varchar(512),@sep char(1))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
GO
```

And you call the procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @TVP PhoneNumberType
DECLARE @textToSplit VARCHAR(512)='0412589, 0425896, 04789652'
INSERT INTO @TVP
SELECT
    split.s
FROM
    dbo.Split(@textToSplit,',') AS split

EXEC usp_InsertPhoneNumbers @TVP
```

Comment: This seems awesome, but I don't understand how can fill `@TVP` by `numbers` NVarchar argument?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an XML parameter to your stored procedure.

You would pass in a XML such as:

```
<phones>
 <phone>
  <memberid>12</memberid>
  <number>123456789</number>
  <type>Landline</type>
 </phone>
 <phone>
  <memberid>12</memberid>
  <number>987654321</number>
  <type>Mobile</type>
 </phone>
</phones>
```

to a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.stp_InsertPhoneNumbers
   @numbersXML xml
AS

INSERT INTO Phone(memberid, number, type)
SELECT
   List.Id.query('memberid').value('.', 'int') as memberid,
   List.Id.query('number').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as number,
   List.Id.query('type').value('.', 'varchar(50)') as type
FROM @numbersXML.nodes('/phones/phone') as List(Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the xml or data table in stored procedure. It's possible to pass data table in sql server 2008.

[Refer : How to pass data table to sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295326/should-you-make-multiple-insert-calls-or-pass-xml/10295812#10295812)