# Join Dataset with sql db table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

I need to execute a query like  as given below which contain a dataset in it.

```
UPDATE <OrderDataset> 
SET FKProduct = P.PKProduct 
FROM <OrderDataset> DS 
INNER JOIN tblCustomer C ON DS.FKCustomer = C.PKCustomer 
INNER JOIN tblProduct P ON C.PKCustomer = P.FKCustomer 
INNER JOIN tblStock S ON S.FKProduct = P.PKProduct 
AND DS.RotationNumber = S.RotationNumber 
AND ISNULL(DS.RotationLineNo,'NULL') = ISNULL(S.RotationLineNo,'NULL') 
WHERE DS.FKProduct IS NULL
```

Is there any way to implemnt this.

Comment: You can perform this using Linq

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this.

You can pass the table inside the dataset as a parameter to sql server stored procedure ans then do the jon in sp. .

[how to pass data table as parameter to sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295326/should-you-make-multiple-insert-calls-or-pass-xml/10295812#10295812)